# Expected value of the number of steps

Tags: probability

A grid of size NxN is given and 4(N-1) bricks of size 1x1 are also given. The bricks are scattered in the grid and you have to move all the bricks(which are not on perimeter) to the perimeter of the grid. The 1 unit Manhatten distance considered as 1 step. Calculate the expected value of the number of steps taken to bring all the bricks on the perimeter of the grid.

PS: This question is the part of interview of machine learning profile in Directi.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Can you please post some of your own thoughts and efforts?  This community will typically look down on posts that look like 'Please do this for me'.  That's why it gets downvoted.

Comment: Second what @Bram28 wrote.  Also, useful information would be where this problem comes from.  Is it homework?  If so, what course is it?  If not, did it come from a practical problem?  Is it a situation where approximate numerical results are useful?  Would Monte Carlo simulation help?  Or is an approximate but first-principles rule of thumb better?

Answer (score 2):

The question does not specify if the strategy to move the bricks is to be the one that uses the least number of steps. That sounds like a terribly difficult problem. Perhaps the goal is to find an approximate solution, at least to find out the coefficients of the leading powers of $N$.

Not having any background in game theory, here is my simple minded estimate. The figure below suggests that the bricks in the shaded triangle will be used to populate the section of the perimeter below it.

[image]

The average number of bricks that start in area $A$ is $N_A\approx(N-1)/4$. On average, bricks in that area have to move down $N/8$ steps. To spread them to fill all $N/4$ spots, some horizontal steps are required to even them out. Let the average number of such steps per brick be $h$, perhaps $h\approx1$. For area $A$ the total number of steps is
$$
E[S_A]\approx{(N-1)\over4}\left({N\over8}+h\right)\approx{N^2\over32}+{7N\over32}$$
The mean vertical distance for bricks in triangle $B$ from the boundary is two thirds of that for the bricks in square $A$. There are half the number of bricks. Gaps can be left, so the number of horizontal steps can be reduced, perhaps on average $h/2\approx1/2$.
$$
E[S_B]\approx{(N-1)\over8}\left({N\over12}+{h\over2}\right)\approx{N^2\over96}+{5N\over96}$$
The blocks in triangle $C$ need to be transposed horizontally (right figure above) then transported downward to fill in the gaps left by B. The transposition can be done so that no further horizontal adjustments are necessary. The average horizontal shift for the blocks is ${4\over3}{N\over4}$ steps.The average downward shift is ${4\over3}{N\over4}$.
$$
E[S_C]\approx{(N-1)\over8}{2N\over3}\approx{N^2\over12}-{N\over12}$$
Multiply the sum of all of these by 8 gives:
$$E[S]\approx N^2+{3N\over2}$$
Given the simple approach, perhaps $E[S]\approx N^2$ for $N\gg1$ is a sufficient summary for a basic algorithm for moving the bricks.